# Point content of a folder to another folder

Tags: shell, raspberry-pi, raspbian

I want to know how can I show the content of a folder from another folder. So, take this example:

```
/home/pi/nas/user1 [1]
/home/pi/nas/user2 [2]
```

folder with content inside: `/home/pi/nas/download`[3]

I want display the content of `[3]` inside the `[1]` and `[2]` folders, how can I do this?

Thanks.

Comment: Consider using a symlink to expose the `download` folder as a sub-object of those two folders.

Comment: @cdhowie thanks, I'm not a linux expert, could you please show me an example?

Comment: `ln -s /home/pi/nas/download /home/pi/nas/user1/` and again for user2.

Comment: @cdhowie I did this, a new folder is create but I can't access to the content, is maybe a permission problem?

Comment: Yes, it could easily be a permissions issue.

Comment: @cdhowie any idea to solve this?

Comment: My guess is that they don't have execute permission on `/home/pi/nas/download`.  You could `chmod +x /home/pi/nas/download` and see if that helps.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/133671/discussion-between-againme-and-cdhowie).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can link the folder 'downloads':

```
ln -s /home/pi/nas/download /home/pi/nas/user1
ln -s /home/pi/nas/download /home/pi/nas/user2
```

The folders user1 and user2 must not exist in advance.

Comment: the folder is create but I can't access to the content

Comment: If you list user1 or user2, do put a trailing /. In case you cannot access, download folder must have permissions for the current user to read.

Comment: now I get insufficient permission, but still I can't access to the content